# Low ph lawn with high calcium levels

Tags: lawn, fertilizer

[image]

I am looking for recommendations how to fertilize while improving ph without further increasing the already high calcium levels. Any insights would be really appreciated.

Comment: That's the most interesting test results I have seen in a while.  My soil is alkaline with low iron and manganese

Comment: Grow blueberries instead of grass...